# I am trying to understand what is the advantage of using multiple Workspaces vs One workspace with multiple projects in Atlassian stack?

Tags: bitbucket, jira, confluence, workspace

I am trying to organize our company's Atlassian stack. We use Jira, Confluence, and Bitbucket.

I am trying to understand what is the advantage of using multiple Workspaces vs One workspace with multiple projects.

I would like to have the below structure:

Clients -> IBM

-> Microsoft

Our Company

-> Admin

-> Knowledgebase

-> Internal Guides

Same structure with project instead of Workspaces

Our Company -> Workspace

-> Client/IBM

----> repo 1

----> repo 2

-> Our Company

----> Office Management App

----> Something Metadata Permissions Management

----> .........

-> Our Company/Training

----> Testing Repo

Can you give me advice and the benefit of using multiple Workspaces vs One workspace with multiple projects? Maybe it's the apps, or the permissions, or its price issues?

I expect to organize our Atlassian stack(Jira, Confluence, and Bitbucket) in the most efficient way.

Comment: Might help to post on the atlassian forums, no one really answers Atlassian questions on here.